# PHP Spreadsheet Xlsx file export is working with 18000 records. More than 20000 records it is giving 500 server error

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Hi Friends before complaining about question please check all the content once clearly.

I tried multiple solution from the google but no solution is worked for me

1. I have used ob_clean(), ob_end_clean() but same error
2. Increased memory limit and max execution time in PHP ini file and added in function also but same error
3. Checked with multiple headers but same error
4. Same code working fine and downloading excel file without any issue

My $res array will have 48 columns and 240604 records.

```
$res = $data  //$res has 48 columns and 240604 records.
try {
    $i = 2;
    foreach(array_chunk($res, 2000, true) as $key => $value) {
        $sheet->fromArray(
            $value,  
            NULL,       
            'A'.$i     
        );
        $i += 2000;
    }
    $count = (count($res)+1);
    $row = 1;
    $lastColumn = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();
    $lastColumn++;
    for ($column = 'A'; $column != $lastColumn; $column++) {
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
    }
    $styleArrayFirstRow = [
        'font' => [
            'bold' => true,
        ]
    ];
    
    $sheet->getStyle('A1:' . $lastColumn . '1' )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,Q2:Q'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('Q'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('S'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,S2:S'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('S'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('V1:V'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('V'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,V2:V'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('V'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('W1:W'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.000%');

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('X1:X'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('X'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,X2:X'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('X'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Y'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,Y2:Y'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('Y'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);
    
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('Z1:Z'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Z'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,Z2:Z'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('Z'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);
    
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AA1:AA'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AA'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AA2:AA'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AA'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AB1:AB'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AB'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AB2:AB'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AB'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AC1:AC'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AC'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AC2:AC'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AC'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AD1:AD'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AD'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AD2:AD'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AD'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AE1:AE'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AE'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AE2:AE'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AE'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AF1:AF'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AF'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AF2:AF'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AF'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AG1:AG'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AG'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AG2:AG'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AG'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AH1:AH'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AH'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AH2:AH'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AH'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AI1:AI'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AI'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AI2:AI'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AI'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AJ1:AJ'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0%');

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AL1:AL'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AM1:AM'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AM'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AM2:AM'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AM'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AN1:AN'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AN'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AN2:AN'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AN'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AO1:AO'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AO'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AO2:AO'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AO'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AP1:AP'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AP'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AP2:AP'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AP'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AQ1:AQ'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AQ'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AQ2:AQ'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AQ'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AR1:AR'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AR'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AR2:AR'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AR'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AS1:AS'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AT1:AT'.($count+1))->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('#,##0.00');
    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AT'.($count+1),'=SUBTOTAL(9,AT2:AT'.$count.')');
    $sheet->getStyle('AT'.($count+1) )->applyFromArray($styleArrayFirstRow);

    $filename = FCPATH."assets\podata_".$my.".xlsx";
    $filename2 = "podata_".$my.".xlsx";

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filename2);
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    //$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);
    // set_time_limit(0);
    // ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    // ob_end_clean();
    // ob_start();
    $writer->save($filename);
    //$writer->save('php://output');
    //$content = file_get_contents($filename);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage());
}
```

I used try catch also to print error. But it is not printing any error. directly going to 500 server error page - unable to handle request

I also used error display function but it is also not giving any error.

Comment: Try removing anything that isn't directly needed to create the spreadsheet first, all of the styling could be removed to see if the basic content is created as expected.

Comment: Clearly you already know that something that breaks when things get big is a resource problem. php is not very good at telling you what went wrong when it runs out of memory; it doesn't have the memory to allocate to the error handler to print out the problem. I would experiment with `ini_set('memory_limit, '1G')` at the top of your code, and fiddle with the number to see how much you actually need. `phpspreadsheet` chews up a lot of memory.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I already used ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); to use memory limit without any restrictions. and same has been configured in php ini file

Comment: Hi Nigel Ren, I did all the testing's by putting exit() line by line. it is working fine before $writer->save() method.

Comment: The limit on the memory might come from outside of php, then. I don't know anything about the environment you are running in. However, it's also possible (though not terribly likely) that a specific record in your data is breaking things. It might be worth trying running a test with only half of that data set, then the other half. If one succeeds and the other fails, maybe it's not memory after all. But it's probably memory. Ultimately my solution to resource issues with phpspreadsheet was to abandon it and export csv instead.

Comment: Hi Jerry, I did all the required testing's and finally i posted this question. I did data into two parts. Both parts downloading successfully. No data issue is there. Worked fine with first 11000 records and remaining 2 set of records.